# Android findviewbyid in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

I am trying to show the date in my button when i set the date. I have tried two things. This is my code

```
 Button mButton;
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_add_semesters, container,false);
    mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSemesterStarts);
    // you can use your textview.
    return super.onCreateView(inflater,null,null);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month= calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog;
    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    mButton.setText(date);
}
```

This doesnt't work. Even if I change the onCreateView method to return the view instead of returning super, I get an error. 
I get this error even when i return view.
Please what am i doing wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pchqd.png)

Comment: Please share your error so we also know what is going on

Comment: have you checked by putting log in date string

Comment: return view and add your logcat.

Comment: If I return view, I get an error when I click on the button. I am not even able to choose the date. The error I get is in the image in my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dialog fragment, try it like this:

```
private View mLayout;
private ViewGroup mContainer;

@Nullable @override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContainer = container;
    if (getShowsDialog()) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
    return getLayout(inflater, container);
}

 private View getLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_add_semesters, container,false);
    return mLayout;
}


@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
    long timestamp = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    Button button = (Button) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnSemesterStarts)
    button.setText(date);
```

}

Comment: Now im getting a null pointer exception after I set the date right before it should show on the button :(

Answer (score 0):

I tried something that worked. I used a constructor instead of onCreateView. 
I'd paste the code here. Hope it helps someone else. :)

```
Button mButton;

EditText txtdate;
public PickerDialogs(Button btn){
    mButton = btn;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month= calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog;
    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
    String date=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
    mButton.setText(date);
}
```